# What is a study trying to synthesise different meanings of a root (synchronically) called?

Tags: terminology, words, ancient, dead-languages

A relatively straightforward research question in the study of dead languages is of the form: "We have root XYZ that means A in context P and B in context Q. How can we generalise A and B to arrive at a general meaning for XYZ?" The question can be approached both from a diachronic perspective ("How did meanings A and B derive from older, more general meaning C?") and from a synchronic perspective ("What do A and B have in common, and what aspects characterise both?").

An example of a diachronic approach would be [Gluck (1976). *The root lḥm in Hebrew and in the Semitic languages*. OTSWA (19), pp. 41–43](https://journals.co.za/content/otswa/19/1/AJA0000017_40).
An example of a synchronic approach would be [Kotzé (2016). *Comments on the Uses and Meanings of אין in the Masoretic Text of the Hebrew Bible: Revisiting Vriezen.* Hebrew Studies (57), pp. 17–38](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/641346).

How would I call such a study, particularly one with a synchronic approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describing the meaning of a word (lemma/root) is what a lexicographer does. So I'd call this a lexicographic study.